# Which ORM should I use for Expressjs and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm looking for a simple-to-use, reasonable-performance ORM, which supports caching, many-to-one and many-to-many relations.
I work with Mysql and Expressjs, what is the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a glance to Sequelize : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/